# FIltering sessions in bigquery where "x event happened"

Tags: google-bigquery

I would be sending my ugliest X-mas jumper to a kind soul, that can help me out with this please: I am in a bit of a trouble because I am not sure how to "complete" this SQL, so that: only those sessions are included where an event was triggered with `eventCategory = x  AND eventAction = Click` (meaning: 1 specific event has to fullfill this criteria, not like "ok there are 24 events here, 1 of them is eventCategory = x and oh, there is another one, that works for eventAction = Click). I hope that I could explain it in a sensible way.

```sql
SELECT
  device.deviceCategory AS device_category,
  device.operatingSystem AS operating_system,
  COUNT(DISTINCT CONCAT(fullvisitorid, CAST(visitstarttime AS string))) AS Sessions,
  COUNT(DISTINCT hits.`transaction`.transactionid) AS Transactions,
  COUNT(DISTINCT hits.`transaction`.transactionid) / COUNT(DISTINCT CONCAT(fullvisitorid, CAST(visitstarttime AS string))) AS Ecommerce_Conversion_Rate,
  (SUM(hits.TRANSACTION.transactionrevenue)/1000000)/COUNT(DISTINCT hits.TRANSACTION.transactionid) AS avg_order_value
FROM
  `my_data_source`AS sessions,
  UNNEST(hits) AS hits
WHERE
  totals.visits = 1
  AND parse_DATE('%y%m%d',
    _TABLE_SUFFIX) BETWEEN "2022-12-02" AND "2022-12-04"
  AND device.deviceCategory != "tablet"
GROUP BY
  device.deviceCategory
ORDER BY
  device.deviceCategory
```

I do not have a solid idea how to filter my sessions in such a way. If any details are unclear about my question, feel free to comment. Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To filter the session with the specific events:

```sql
...
WHERE
 ...
 AND hits.eventInfo.eventCategory = 'x' 
 AND hits.eventInfo.eventAction = 'Click'
...
```

More in the docs: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3437719?hl=en